# Establecer foco o deshabilitar input en modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

Tengo un modal que se abre con la siguiente instruccion:

```
$('#mEditarLaboral').modal('show', function () {
    debugger;
    $('#MainContent_txtEditarFechaInicio', this).focus();
    txtEditarIngresos.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Ahí estan los dos intentos que hice para ver si podia deshabilitar o focusear elementos dentro de este. Lo que me da la sensación que sucede es que los elementos dentro del modal todavia no se iniciaron debido al efecto fade del modal y eso hace que no entren a la instrucción de la función dentro del modal.

Alguna sugerencia de como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Prueba con el evento show.bs.modal: $('#mEditarLaboral').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){...

Comment: Para inactivar, usa `$('#txtEditarIngresos').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` y para hacer `focus`, usa `$('#txtEditarFechaInicio').focus();`

Answer (score 1):

Espero te ayude lo siguiente:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#MainContent_txtEditarFechaInicio").focus();
    });
});
</script>

    <style>
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>

    <div class="bs-example">
        <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
        <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Demo</a>

        <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputName">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" id="MainContent_txtEditarFechaInicio" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No funciona, al usar **$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal'** directamente no me abre el modal.

Comment: Tienes que agregar las referencias js. El ejemplo tal y como está, funciona correctamente.

Comment: No eran las referencias, necesitaba agregar  **.modal('show');**